# What API can I use to get FAA NOTAMS or will this one I found work?

Tags: xml, rest, api

I am not sure if this is the correct place to ask this because it has to do with APIs with XML/JSON/SOAP, but it also has to do with aviation.

I am in dire need to find an API associated with the FAA to get NOTAMs for areas and airports. NOTAMs are Notices to Airmen, and it will be a useful feature in a service I am creating.

I have done extensive searching for a NOTAMs API, but I cannot find anything except this:
https://notams.aim.faa.gov/notamWFS/

However, this website requires registration which is just a broken link. Any suggestions on how to use this?

Do you know of any other NOTAM APIs available?
Also, if possible, do you know of a weather API which has the same information included in an ATIS/AWOS reporting station?

I was able to find working APIs for US regulations and general weather (not specific enough) and pilot information, but I cannot find any for specific weather or NOTAMs.

EDIT: A friend of mine was able to click the registration button, and it didn't give him an error. He sent me the link and I am now trying to register on the site I found.

Comment: Which registration link are you using?  The "register for service" link in the upper right corner fails 404 Not Found but the _In order to use this service, you need to first register an account following this link._ link under **Request Methods and Encoding** asks for an email address?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using JavaScript, you can use the [`notams`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/notams) package. This package retrieves and parses data from this FAA website:

- https://pilotweb.nas.faa.gov/

I've used this successfully as shown below. You can examine how this package works by looking at its source code. You can use this to port to another language if you wish.

- https://github.com/fdesjardins/notams/blob/master/index.js

You can use this package like this:

```
var notams = require('notams');
notams(['PADK', 'PADU'], { format: 'DOMESTIC' }).then(results => {
  console.log(results)
})
```

Results:

```
[ { icao: 'PADK',
    notams: 
     [ '!ADK 05/012 ADK NAV ILS RWY 23 LOC NOT MNT 1805170855-1806091400EST\n',
       '!ADK 05/010 ADK NAV ILS RWY 23 GP OUT OF SERVICE 1805090841-1805311500EST\n',
       '!ADK 03/001 ADK NAV NDB OUT OF SERVICE 1503030545-PERM\n',
       '!FDC 7/7064 ADK SPECIAL ADAK, Adak Island, AK.\nILS OR LOC/DME RWY 23, AMDT 2...\nPROCEDURE NA EXCEPT FOR AIRCRAFT EQUIPPED WITH SUITABLE RNAV SYSTEM\nWITH GPS,\nADK NDB OUT OF SERVICE. 1712191423-1807311423EST\n',
       '!FDC 7/7063 ADK ODP ADAK, Adak Island, AK.\nTAKEOFF MINIMUMS AND (OBSTACLE) DEPARTURE PROCEDURES AMDT 2...\nDEPARTURE PROCEDURE NA EXCEPT FOR AIRCRAFT EQUIPPED WITH SUITABLE\nRNAV SYSTEM WITH GPS,\nADK NDB OUT OF SERVICE. 1712191423-1807311423EST\n' ] },
  { icao: 'PADU',
    notams: 
     [ '!DUT 05/099 DUT APRON ALL FICON WET OBSERVED AT 1805281628. 1805281628-1805291628\n',
       '!DUT 05/098 DUT TWY ALL FICON WET OBSERVED AT 1805281627. 1805281628-1805291628\n',
       '!DUT 05/097 DUT RWY 31 FICON 5/5/5 100 PCT WET OBS AT 1805281626. 1805281626-1805291626\n',
       '!DUT 05/096 DUT RWY 13 FICON 5/5/5 100 PCT WET OBS AT 1805281626. 1805281626-1805291626\n' ] } ]
```

Comment: Nice! Idea if exist something for Java?

Answer (score 0):

I tried accessing Aeronautical Common Services Data Query (ACS-DQ) V 2.0 through [NAS Service Registry and Repository](https://nsrr.faa.gov/) after registering in six places I was informed that this service wouldn't be available until spring 2019.

For weather, I use [aviation weather](https://www.aviationweather.gov/) to get Terminal Aerodrome Forecasts (TAFs)